# Neighborhood of an orthogonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A\in O(n)$ be an orthogonal matrix and let $\vec{a}_1,\dots,\vec{a}_n$ be its rows. For a vector $\vec{v}=[v_1,\dots,v_n]$, let $\max(\vec{v})=\max\{|v_1|,\dots,|v_n|\}$. Prove or disprove that if $\max(\vec{a}_i)<1$ for every $i$, then for every small neighborhood of $A$ there exists $B\in O(n)$ such that $\max(\vec{b}_i)>\max(\vec{a}_i)$ for every $i$.

For me the general approach to this kind of problem is to form a map $f:O(n)\to\mathbb{R}^n$ where $f(A)=[\max\{\vec{a}_1\},\dots,\max\{\vec{a}_n\}]$ and analysis the induced map between tangent spaces, but the $\max$ map here is kind of painful. Any thoughts?

Comment: Why not consider $(1+\epsilon)A$. This would also be orthogonal with $\max(\vec{b}_i)>\max(\vec{a}_i)$ for every $i$, and can be made to lie within an arbitrary small ball around $A$. Hope I follow your question correctly.

Comment: @DSM Why would this be an orthogonal matrix though? The length of every row would be $1+\epsilon$ so each row would not be a unit vector.

Comment: I am sorry, I assumed you wanted only orthogonality, and not orthonormality. In that case, my comment does not mean much.

Comment: A naive constructive approach that comes to mind: of course, a permutation matrix $P$ is a matrix that satisfies the requirements of $B$ except that it might fail to be in a sufficiently small neighborhood of $A$. If we look at the path $p:[0,1] \to \Bbb R^{n \times n}$ defined by $p(t) = (1-t)A + tP$ and project onto $O(n)$ (via the "orthogonal procrustes" polar decomposition method), then it must hold that $p(t)$ *eventually* satisfies the necessary requirements. Perhaps it is possible to guarantee that this happens for sufficiently small $t$ for the right choice of $P$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I have thought about that, but there exists a counterexample since the max of two rows may occur at the same column (I got an explicit 4$\times$4 counterexample but probably too large for a comment).

Comment: $$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 a & \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}-a^2} & \frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{2} \\
 a & \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}-a^2} & -\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} \\
 -\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}-a^2} & a & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} \\
 -\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}-a^2} & a & -\frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{2} \\
\end{array}
\right) \;, \quad \frac{1}{2} < a < \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}$$

Comment: @student Could you elaborate more on your comment? Thanks!

Comment: It’s the case you mentioned where multiple maxima are in the same column. The upper limit $a=1/\sqrt{2}$ also gives a matrix $A$ where it’s not immediately clear to me what rotation produces a valid $B$.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a constructive argument and I'm too shaky on my differential geometry to flesh it out completely off the top of my head, but I believe the following approach might be fruitful.

Fix a matrix $A$. For each $i$, let $m_i$ denote an index for which $|a_{i,m_i}| = \max(\vec a_i)$.  Without loss of generality, suppose that $a_{i,m_i}>0$ for all $i$. Let $U$ denote the relatively open set 
$$
U = \{B : \text{for all }i, \max(\vec b_i) = b_{i,m_i}; b_{i,m_i} > |b_{ij}| \text{ for } j \neq m_i; \text{ and } b_{im_i} > a_{im_i}\}.
$$
Consider the function $f:U \to \Bbb R^n$ given by
$$
f(B) = [\max(\vec b_1), \dots, \max(\vec b_n)] = [b_{1,m_1},\dots,b_{1,m_n}].
$$
$f$ is the restriction of a linear and therefore differentiable, and (I think) the differential $df$ has full rank over $U$. It follows by [differential geometry argument of some kind] that for a sequence in $f(U)$ converging to the boundary point $f(A)$ of $f(U)$, there is a corresponding sequence in $U$ converging to $A$.

Comment: Let's fill in the details to see if my understanding is correct: $df$ has full rank because $df$ is a $n\times 2n$ matrix (Jacobian of $f$), all rows has only one non-zero entry, and such non-zero entry occurs at different columns for each row. Hence $f$ is a smooth submersion and $f:U\to f(U)$ is surjective. Then we are done as we can select a sequence in $f(U)$ converging to $f(A)$, and there is a corresponding sequence in $U$ converging to $A$.

Comment: I am not sure about the last part (sequence) though. Could you provide a reference on that? I think it is true because constant rank maps are projection maps up to a coordinate change, and for projection maps it would be obvious.

Comment: @LoCelso As I said, very shaky when it comes to differential geometry; I'm honestly not sure where to look. If I find something to connect the dots there, I'll let you know.